# shared iAd instance not displaying for child view initially

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I am integrating iAds into an iOS 6 app with a UITabBarController and UINavigationController and a bunch of UITableView-based screens and have it mostly working with one glaring exception. When I navigate from a parent to child view controller, my banner view does not appear until the ADBannerView delegate methods are invoked (when a new ad is served) even if I already have an ad.

What I want is when I have an ad displayed on the parent and click to the child, I want the ad to appear immediately. However, what is happening is that the ad banner disappears and does reappear until the delegate methods are invoked to update it. Stepping through the debugger it all looks like it should work. I am sure it is something trivial I am not doing, but am stuck. Help!

As I put in the comments, it seems to be that the _contentView frame size is incorrect at the point where the code is placing the ad in the view. With auto-layout off, it places the ad correct initially, but with each new ad, the banner moves up the screen. With auto-layout on, the initial display of the ad is in the wrong place, but subsequent calls (or rotation calls) the ad is in the correct location.

Here is the relevant code:

I have a singleton class that manages the creation of the ADBannerView instance I want to share. The singleton just does the allocation once; otherwise it returns the banner view:

```
- (ADBannerView *) getAdBannerSingleton
{
    if ( bannerView == nil )
    {
        DDLogInfo(@"iAds: Creating our initial banner view") ;
        bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner] ;

        // to handle rotation properly
        [bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth] ;
    }

    return bannerView ;
}
```

I have a base class that has a View --> SubView --> UITableView (in a XIB) and manages the ADBannerView and serves as the delegate. My concrete parent/child classes inherit from the base class, but do nothing special themselves (they are blissfully unaware of the ads).

```
@implementation SSSAdEnabledTableViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize contentView = _contentView;
@synthesize bannerView = _bannerView ;

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil] ;

    // this class does not need to do anything special as there are no concrete instances of it

    return self ;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //
    // manage our ad
    //
    DDLogInfo(@"iAds: Managing ad View from viewWillAppear for %@", 
                                            NSStringFromClass([self class])) ;
    [self manageAdView] ;
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated] ;
    // no effect with our without the call below
    [_bannerView removeFromSuperview];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_tableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES] ;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    self.contentView = nil ;
    self.tableView = nil ;
    self.bannerView = nil ;
}

#pragma mark -- iAd framework methods

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    DDLogInfo(@"iAds: Banner ad successfully loaded for %@", NSStringFromClass([self class])) ;
    [self manageAdView] ;
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    return YES ;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    // don't think we have to do anything?
}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DDLogError(@"Error loading iAd for %@. Reason: %@",
               NSStringFromClass([self class]),
               [error localizedDescription]) ;

    [self manageAdView] ;
}

#pragma mark -- ad banner helper methods

//
// Get our shared banner view instance
//
- (void)createAdBannerView
{
    // get the banner view instance
    _bannerView = [[SSSStoreManager sharedStore] getAdBannerSingleton] ;

    // make us the delegate
    DDLogInfo(@"iAds: Setting %@ to be our banner delegate", NSStringFromClass([self class])) ;

    // set it to be the delegate
    [_bannerView setDelegate:self] ;
}

//
// Based on the ad status, make room for it in our view or hide it
//
- (void)manageAdView
{
    // make sure we always have a banner view to work with here
    if ( _bannerView == nil )
    {
        DDLogInfo(@"Banner View is Nil; Creating it for %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
        [self createAdBannerView] ;
    }

    // will hold our banner dimensions and position
    CGRect bannerFrame = CGRectZero;
    // our inner view dimensions and position
    CGRect contentViewFrame = _contentView.frame;

    // make sure all of the changes happen at one time
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fixupViews" context:nil];

    // is the banner loaded and should it be visible?
    if ( _bannerView.bannerLoaded == YES )
    {
        DDLogInfo(@"iAds: Showing banner view for %@", NSStringFromClass([self class])) ;
        bannerFrame.size = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentViewFrame.size];

        contentViewFrame.size.height -= bannerFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentViewFrame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        DDLogInfo(@"iAds: Hiding banner view for %@", NSStringFromClass([self class])) ;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentViewFrame.size.height;
    }

    // reset our content view based on whether we have an ad to show
    _contentView.frame = contentViewFrame ;

    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
    _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: So, it appears the problem has something to do with the content frame, but I have no clue why. In the parent view, it says the content frame is 367 which takes into account the nav bar and tab bar. However, for some reason, in the child, it thinks the content view is 548 (full screen). Neither class does anything different as they both inherit from the class I documented above. Thoughts?

Comment: Further, it seems auto-layout is affecting this as well. With it on, I have the problem described above. If I turn auto-layout off, the ad appears fine the first time every time, but subsequent updates keep moving the ad up (because contentView is being resized each time).